# Laravel get user with Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-5

I have a permission / roles setup for my users.
this is via 6 tables

- users
- roles
- permissions
- role_user
- permission_role
- permission_user

And the User Class has the following functions:

```
public function permissions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}

public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

the Permission Class has the following functions

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

And finally Role has the following functions:

```
public function permissions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

So now I would like to request a user with all the permissions listed and all roles listed, so I created:

```
$u = \Auth::user();
return User::with('roles.permissions')->with('permissions')->find($u->id);
```

which returned somthing like

```
{
    id: 53,
    name: "name",
    username: "username",
    avatar: "",
    email: "email",
    created_at: "2016-02-20 14:36:54",
    updated_at: "2016-02-20 14:36:54",
    roles: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "edit_forum",
        label: "Edit Forum",
        created_at: "2016-02-20 12:33:50",
        updated_at: "2016-02-20 12:33:50",
        permissions: [{
            id: 2,
            name: "Testing stuff",
            label: null,
            created_at: "2016-02-20 16:50:02",
            updated_at: "2016-02-20 16:50:02"
        }]
    }],
    permissions: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Testing",
        label: null,
        created_at: "2016-02-20 16:50:02",
        updated_at: "2016-02-20 16:50:02"
    }]
}
```

so as you can see, the permissions of it's roles are in a seperated array, now I'm trying 2 things, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the functions:

first:
Get all the permissions of the user itself and the permissions in 1 array.

Second:
Get this via a single scope/function

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The 2 things I'm trying to archieve

Answer (score 2):

The `Permission` Class has the following function:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

This should be a `many-to-many`relationship instead of `one-to-many` so you write the method like this:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

So the `permission_user` pivot table will be used to maintain the relationship and regarding your code, you can do something like this:

```
$u = \Auth::user(); // get the authenticated User
return $u->load('roles.permissions'); // Load the roles and permissions of loaded User
```

So, no need to make more queries for loading permissions and roles separately. You can use something like this:

```
foreach($u->roles as $role) {

    // $role->title; // for example

    foreach($role->permissions as $permission) {

        // $permission->title; // for example
    }
}
```

Remember that, `$u->roles` will return a collection where in each `$role` (when you call `$role->permissions`) the `permissions` will be also a collection.

---

*Note: You may follow [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-5-1-x-acl-middleware#.VsiU6X197IV) of mine to get more idea.*

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. but how would you fetch the user specific permissions? so the ones they won't get via a role?

Comment: `Auth::user()->permissions` will give you authenticated user's permissions through `permission_user` pivot table.

Comment: I know, that's what's already in the output when doing the `->with() `commands, but I want, 1 list with **all** the permissions